# database missing? homebrew install and uninstall

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, homebrew, psql

ok so I did something very wrong but im not sure how to fix it.  I am on osx yosemite and am very new to rails

below are the commands I typed into the terminal

```
**Anna$ psql**
   **psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
   Is the server running locally and accepting
   connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?**
Anna$ postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
   LOG:  database system was shut down at 2015-07-10 15:24:50 EDT
   LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
   LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
   LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
   ^CLOG:  received fast shutdown request
   LOG:  aborting any active transactions
   LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
   LOG:  shutting down
   LOG:  database system is shut down
Anna$ launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
   /Users/Anna/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist: No such file or directory
Anna$ launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
   /Users/Anna/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist: No such file or directory
Anna$ ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/postgresql/*.plist 
  ./homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist -> /usr/local/opt/postgresql/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
Anna$ ~/Library/LaunchAgents
  -bash: /Users/Anna/Library/LaunchAgents: is a directory
Anna$ ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/postgresql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
   /Users/Anna/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist -> /usr/local/opt/postgresql/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
Anna$ launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
**Anna$ psql**
  **psql: FATAL:  database "Anna" does not exist**
```

and then i uninstalled homebrew, but every time i try to reinstall it i get this:

```
Anna$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
  -bash: /Users/Anna/.rbenv/shims/ruby: No such file or directory
```

which is the same command i used to install it in the first place (which worked perectly)

any help to fix this and to tell me what i did wrong so i dont do it again would really be appreciated

Comment: First things first, from the error logs I can see that there is some problem with ruby installation on your system. can run the following command on terminal and see the results? `which ruby`. If no ruby is installed you can use https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#installing-ruby-versions assuming you already have rbenv

Comment: /usr/bin/ruby
i get this when i run which ruby